# Intersection of $\rho_{xx}$ and $\rho_{xy}$ in Drude magnetotransport

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, quantum-hall-effect

Okay, so I've recently been working through the rather elementary derivation of the Hall effect in a 2 dimensional electron gas, using the Drude model.

The idea is that with an E field in the x direction and a B field in the z direction, we find the 2 by 2 resistivity tensor $\rho$ for which it holds that $\vec{E} = \rho \vec{j}$ (2 dimensional vectors, as our motion is confined in the plane).

Now, this tensor has two unique components $\rho_{xx} = \frac{m^*}{n_s \tau |e|^2}$ and $\rho_{xy} = \frac{B}{|e|n_s}$ where $m^*$ is the effective mass, $n_s$ is the electron density and $\tau$ is the phenomenological scattering time.

Doing a simple calculation we find that these are equal for $B = \frac{m^*}{|e|\tau} = \frac{1}{\mu}$ where $\mu$ is the mobility of the electrons. So we have that, when these two components are equal, $\mu B = 1$. Or, rewriting in terms of cyclotron frequency $\omega_c$, we have that $\omega_c \tau = 1$.

My question is, quite simply, what is the significance of the equality happening at this point? I understand that this means that here the cyclotron frequency is on the same timescale as the scattering time, for example, but I can't think of any additional meaning or significance of this specific point.

Comment: I should add that I understand that when $\mu B = 1$ we are probably well into the Shubnikov de Haas regime, which might make the question a little less relevant. I'm not 100% sure it does, but it is worth considering.